# Not receiving emergency alerts for the Ukraine test broadcast on September 7th

Tags: samsung, android-11, cell-broadcast

Recently, I received an SMS that the State Emergency Service of Ukraine will test the new Cell Broadcast notification system, and that test notifications will come from September 7th. Why don't they come? All emergency alerts in notification settings are enabled, and airplane mode is disabled.

SMS:

> З 07.09.22 розпочнеться тестування нової системи інформування про надзвичайні ситуації. ДСНС надсилатиме тестові повідомлення зі звуковим сигналом на телефон. Тестування не потребує дій з вашої сторони. Ознайомтесь з деталями за посиланням: https://dsns.gov.ua/test

Settings:

[image: Emergency alerts settings]

Phone: Samsung Galaxy A10s, Android 11, all updates installed.
I live in Dnipropetrovsk region.

Comment: The link on the SMS https://dsns.gov.ua/test/ has more information about the test. Do all of the conditions apply in your case, including the location?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, all conditios are met

Comment: Hi, FYI, I refunded the bounty since I'm not sure if it's possible for anyone to diagnose or even guess the reason why you didn't get it on Sep 7 but got it on Sep 14. I hope you understand.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you for canceling the bounty, I was looking for an option to cancel it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

September 14, 14:28 received a test alert.
[image: Alert screenshot]